# Clean Architecture History/Activity Logging

Tags: clean-architecture

Where should I put on when to log the actions of the user, on Domain, or Presentation layer?

**If Presentation Layer** *(Assuming MVP)*: After the presenter calls the interactor/usecase, it will call another usecase to add an activity/history log.

**If Domain Layer**: After the interactor/usecase itself does the action, it will save to the history/activity logs storage.

I'm confused if history/activity log is part of presentation layer as the text/action that will be log (eg string: User like this comment) looks like not needed on domain layer.

But I'm also confused if history logging is part of an application logic, which is Domain layer. Because if I'll put it on Domain layer, the log text format will be hard coded on usecase/interactor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you want to achieve. If you just want to collect which UI elements and which parts of the UI are used by the users most often, adding the logging to the Presentation Layer might be sufficient.

If your focus is on logging which functionality is used by your users most often and how it is used then logging should be in the Domain Layer/Application Layer. In this case the decision which information is logged for each "activity" is part of the business rules.
You may want to use something like a Repository Pattern to keep the Domain Layer independent from the actual writing of the log, or use a logging library that exposes an interface for the logger class, which you inject in your domain objects.

Comment: Just to clarify, "keep the domain layer independent from actual writing of the log" you mean that I should have only like `logUpdatedName()` function then the actual string which will be inserted will be handled by the Data layer? I don't think this is how I understand the data layer, as data layer must only know how to write/read data, in which, it must only know how to read or write a history. It should never know or care, what should be read or written.

Comment: I meant to say: the domain layer should decide WHEN to log and WHAT to log but it shouldn't know whether the log goes to e.g. flat file or SQL database

Comment: oh okay we're the same on that one. I'm thinking of if it is ok to create separate tables for each action that I like to add, like: `logUpdatedProfile(oldValue: String, newValue: String, field: String, date: Date), logSaveId(idObject: IDObject, date: Date)` something like this. Then I'll another object that will hold all of this lists and modify it as I want to display on UI.

Comment: Having multiple tables sounds reasonable as you want to log different data structures. Anyhow, from architecture perspective this would be an implementation detail.

Comment: Ok thanks for the input, I'll try this and see the problems that will I encounter.